# Rails3 rails console crashes throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying Rails 3 and I am using RVM to manage the ruby versions. Using RVM I had installed ruby versions 1.8.7, 1.9.1 and 1.9.2.

When I do "rails console" I am getting the following error and console isn't starting:

```
/home/syed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
  from /home/syed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
  from /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `require'
  from /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Since I don't require 1.9.1 any more to work with Rails 3, I un-installed it using the following command:

```
rvm uninstall ruby-1.9.1
```

Still rails console crashes. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and RVM to manage different ruby installations.

I had to do:

rvm package install readline
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-readline-dir=/home/syed/.rvm/usr/

following the instructions here: 
http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ and with help from 
Sutto at #rvm irc.freenode.net

Comment: This did not work for me as is, but following the instructions at http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/2010/11/25/readline-error-with-rvm-and-rails-3.html I managed to get it working on my RVM install.